# How should I proceed to capitalize the first letter of a filter when it is on the beginning of the sentence?

Tags: php, regex

I have some filters on my forums, something like: when a user posts "hello" the filter modifies the word to "ohai!".

But when a user posts Hello the filter still modify the word to "ohai!", not "Ohai!".

I know this is fixed using regex, but I don't know how.

Comment: You can make a regex case-insensitive (so it will catch both "hello" and "Hello") but I have not seen a regex engine capable of determining the case of the matched string and then replacing the string with the same case. That's going to require some actual coding (in whatever programming language your forums are written in). Or, you could have two regexes, on which matches "hello" and another which matches "Hello" and replace the text accordingly. That'd get pretty gnarly though (covering cases like "hELLO" and "HELLO" and ...)

Comment: which language are u using....

Comment: I'm using PHP, Kusaba X.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using PHP you can use ucfirst(); (Uppercase First letter)

For example:

```
$filter= "ohai";
echo ucfirst($filter);
```